# Overlaps Function in Redshift

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a true/false flag that is true when two date parameter sets contain some overlapping time or days. My understanding is that Postgres already has a function for this called 'OVERLAPS', as seen in this documentation from 8.4:

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html][1]

When I try to use OVERLAPS in redshift, it seems the function works, see example below:

```
SELECT (DATE '2001-02-16', DATE '2001-12-21') OVERLAPS
   (DATE '2001-10-30', DATE '2002-10-30');
```

However, when I try to use it to populate a column, it generates an error, see example below where the result should always be true, because its comparing a a period to itself. In this example I use timestamp with timezone, but i've tried this also without timezone, and as just date, all of which fail with the same error.

```
CREATE TABLE date_table (
  variable  VARCHAR,
  date_start TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  date_end TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
  )
;
INSERT INTO date_table VALUES ('max_date', TO_TIMESTAMP('2017/04/05 
00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2017/04/09 00:00:00', 
'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
;
INSERT INTO date_table VALUES ('min_date', TO_TIMESTAMP('2016/04/06 
00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2016/04/15 00:00:00', 
'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
;
INSERT INTO date_table VALUES ('min_date', TO_TIMESTAMP('2015/04/01 
00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2015/04/14 00:00:00', 
'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
;

SELECT dt.*, (date_start, date_end) OVERLAPS (date_start, date_end) AS 
overlap_test
FROM date_table dt
```

The error I get is listed below:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT dt.*, (date_start, date_end) OVERLAPS (date_start, date_end) AS overlap_test
FROM date_table dt

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;

Warnings:
Function ""overlaps"(timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone)" not supported.


Execution time: 0.07s
Statement 1 of 1 finished

1 statement failed.
```

Comment: Redshift is based on Postgres 8.0 so reading any manual for a later version makes no sense. Actually reading the Postgres manual makes no sense to begin with, you should consult the Redshift manual: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_SQLCommandRef.html  (`overlaps` does not seem to be documented at all there)

Comment: Regarding the error: your first example uses `DATE` values. In your second example you are using `TIMESTAMP` values. As the error messages says, that's apparently not supported

Comment: Gotcha, my mistake, here would be the link from 8.0 where it is listed. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html It clearly seems usable in Redshift due to the first example returning a result, and 'OVERLAPS' shows up in the redshift reserved list: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_pg_keywords.html Its just curious that redshift seems to have no other documentation of the function.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, as I mentioned i've tried it with date and with timestamp, in both cases it seems to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift is based on Postgres, but it is *not* Postgres. Looking at the functions available in Postgres documentation is not a good idea, the only supported functions in Redshift are those explicitly listed in the Redshift documentation, in this case only [these date and time functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html) are supported. OVERLAPS is not supported, hence the warning message you are getting.

I'm not sure why your first select statement does not trigger this warning, possibly because it is not querying any actual tables.

Comment: That is helpful, I'll stop experimenting with functions not listed in the Redshift documentation, Thanks!